# Como funciona el verificador "?" en React/Next?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

Tengo una consulta, estoy trabajando en un proyecto en React 17 y Next 12, y existe una forma de validar que un objeto no es `null` de una forma que no conocia, algo como:

```
miObjeto?.objetoInterior?.propiedad = value
```

Esto evita hacer cosas como `if(miObjeto && miObjeto.objetoInterior) {...}`

Primero pense que era una caracteristica de JS, pero cuando lo intente en un proyecto de Vue lanzaba errores.

Ahora, quiero hacer una funcion asi:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const body = document.querySelector("body") || null;
    if (mobileMapState === 3) {
      handleOpenMap();
      body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    } else {
      body.style.overflow = "auto";
    }
  }, [mobileMapState]);
```

Y me sucede que quiero asegurarme que `body` no sea `null` antes de hacer `body.style.overflow = "hidden";`, para lo que intento hacer

```
body?.style?.overflow = "hidden";
```

Y recibo un error de Eslint:

> Parsing error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression.

Entonces intento

```
body && body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

Pero el error es el mismo.

La unica forma que encontre de hacer esto fue:

```
  if (body) {
    body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  }
```

Y si bien funciona, me surgen dudas, como por ejemplo porque no puedo usar `?` en este caso, y si hubiera una forma correcta de utilizarla para hacer mas corta la validacion.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se le conoce como encadenamiento opcional

Y lo que hace es simplificar el acceso a los valorers regresando null o undefined si la misma no existe, en vez de marcar error.

Tambien es mas legible que el operador corto circuito.

```
const adventurer = {
  name: 'Alice',
  cat: {
    name: 'Dinah'
  }
};

const dogName = adventurer.dog?.name;
console.log(dogName);
// expected output: undefined

console.log(adventurer.someNonExistentMethod?.());
// expected output: undefined
```

Referencia:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Ahora bien para el desactivar dicha linea

```
adventurer.dog?.name; // eslint-disable-line no-use-before-define
```

O directamente en el config.

```
{ "allowShortCircuit": true, "allowTernary": true }
```

Referencia:

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-expressions

Comment: muchas gracias! no sabia como googlearlo jaja ‍♂️ una pregunta out-of-context... yo intente usar este verificador en un proyecto de Nuxt y me arrojaba errores, no me permitia usarlo, de ahi que pense que era de React/Next, y ahora veo que es de JS. Es necesaria alguna configuracion previa o version minima de node, por ejemplo? Ya que me extraña que no haya funcionado en un archivo .vue

Comment: Es un feacture 2020